# Convert a StreamWriter to an OutputStream in java?

Tags: java, io, stream

I am trying to redirect System.out into a String using System.setOut, which takes a PrintStream. Is there any way to convert a StringWriter into a Stream so that I can pass it to setOut?

Answer (score 28):

You can't do that exactly, since `StringWriter` is a `Writer`, not a `Stream`. But you can do this:

```
// create a ByteArray stream, which will be wrapped by a PrintStream
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
System.setOut(ps);

// print whatever you got
String result = baos.toString();
```